# erro 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer login e retornar na tela o painel de um site pore me e retornado um erro `405 Method Not Allowed` como posso resolver isso ?

```
<?php



$email = '   ';

$senha = '  ';


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://host.com/login');

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_username=$email&_password=$senha');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

$store = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://host.com/dashboard/');

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 

$prok =curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo $prok;


?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem como deduzir o problema, isto é o servidor que você esta tentando acessar que esta emitindo um bloqueio, por exemplo quando um servidor responde com:

> 405 Method Not Allowed

Ele esta querendo dizer que não permite o método que você tentou usar, se tentou `POST` talvez ele não permita `POST`, ou talvez o `curl` esteja tentando enviar POST mas o "verbo" vai marcado como `GET` (se for um bug na tua versão do PHP, o que acho improvável), então tente forçar definir isto:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
```

De resto é só possivel determinar o problema sabendo qual a página que esta tentando acessar.

---

**[Edição]**

Troque a URL do primeiro `CURL` por (note que o correto é `/login_check` e não `/login`):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://minhaconta.payleven.com.br/login_check');
```

E corrija o `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, precisa concatenar e codificar os valores (aspas simples não permitem receber os valores das variaveis):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_username=' . urlencode($email) . '&_password=' . urlencode($senha));
```

E devido a redirecionamento dos servidor recomendo que adicione isto:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Adicione em ambos curls.

Comment: estou tentando acessar a pagina  https://minhaconta.payleven.com.br/login  para criar meu painel personalizado de gerenciamento

Comment: A mensagem toda Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed".

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused

Comment: Agora o codigo de errp retornado é: 301 Moved Permanently

nginx